# Proper validation in Rest Api Django

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have this code in my `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import OnlineMeeting


def valid_name(dob):
    if dob.isalpha() is False:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Name and surname must contain only letters")
    return dob


class MeetingsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OnlineMeeting
        fields = '__all__'


class OnlineMeetingDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    start_time = serializers.TimeField()
    end_time = serializers.TimeField()
    owner_first_name = serializers.CharField(validators=[valid_name])
    owner_last_name = serializers.CharField(validators=[valid_name])
    participant_first_name = serializers.CharField(validators=[valid_name])
    participant_last_name = serializers.CharField(validators=[valid_name])

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['start_time'] > data['end_time']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = OnlineMeeting
        fields = '__all__'
```

I don't inherit `OnlineMeetingDetailSerializer` from `serializers.Serializer` which is used for implenting your own validation, is it bad? Can I also write validation in classes which inherit `serializers.ModelSerializer`?

Comment: :) may be you should read the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer "The ModelSerializer class is the same as a regular Serializer class, except that: ..."

Comment: I read the docs, but I don't know if it's ok to write some additional validation in such class which inherits  ```serializers.ModelSerializer```

Comment: "I read the docs" don't lie to me xD https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly feel free to modify it as you would do with simple`Serializer`